# Process request and return response in chunks

Tags: laravel, request, response, jobs

I'm making a search agreggator and I've been wondering how could I improve the performance of the search.

Given that I'm getting results from different websites, currently I need to wait to receive the results for each provider but this is done one after another so the whole request takes a while to respond.

The easiest solution would be to just make a request from the client for each provider, but this would end up with a ton of request per search, (but if this is the proper way I'll just do it.)

Why I've been wondering is if there's  way to return results everytime a provider responds, so if we have providers A, B and C and B already returned results then send it back to the client. In order for this to work all the searchs would need to run in parallel of course.

Do you know a way of doing this?

I'm trying to build a search experience similar to SkyScanner, that loads results but then you can see it still keeps getting more records and it sorts them on the fly (on client side as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

Caching is the key here. Best practices for external API (or scraping) is to be as little of a 'taker' as possible. So in your Laravel setup, get your results, but cache the results for as long as makes sense for your app. Although the odds in a skyscanner situation is low that two users will make the exact same request, the odds are much higher that a user will make the same request multiple times, or may share the link, etc.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache

```
cache(['key' => 'value'], now()->addMinutes(10));

$value = cache('key');
```

To actually scrape the content, you could use this:

https://github.com/softonic/laravel-intelligent-scraper

Or to use an API which is the nicer route:

https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

On the client side, you could just make a few calls to your own service in separate requests and that would give you your asynchronous feel you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, SkyScanner was just an example but it applies what you say: the odds of two matching records are low given that there's a ton of items to search so this could help but won't solve the issue. My question was more about how (if possible) send response by parts when I get results from each provider

Comment: @KennyHorna anyone who does that does it by sending multiple requests.

Comment: @KennyHorna You could either send them all out at once, and show the results from each one as they come in, or have the requests delayed a few seconds each. Or if you want to intiitate results from the server you could use a service like Pusher.

Comment: Ah I like the Pusher alternative, I hadn't thought about that option